# Aproximation (Proof)

Tags: calculus, analysis, approximation

Can you help me?

If $f$ and $f'$ are continuous at $[a,b]$ (where $a,b\mathbb{\in R}$), then $\forall\epsilon>0$ exists a polynomial $p$ such that $\left\Vert f-p\right\Vert _{\infty}\leq\epsilon$ and $\left\Vert f'-p'\right\Vert _{\infty}\leq\epsilon$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555712/on-finding-polynomials-that-approximate-a-function-and-its-derivative-extension.

Comment: The proof is given in the acctual question text in the link above (the case called $n=1$).