# $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with the norm $\|\varphi\|_{\infty}+\|\varphi'\|_{\infty}$ is separable.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of $C^{\infty}$ functions with compact support in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with the norm $\|\varphi\|_{\infty}+\| \varphi'\|_{\infty}$ separable? And in general with $$\sum_{k=1}^N\|\varphi^{(k)}\|_\infty\,?$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $\mathcal P_{\mathbb Q}$ denote the set of polynomials with rational coefficients. For each $n\in \mathbb N,$ choose $g_n \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ such that $g_n=1$ on $[-n,n].$ Consider $\{g_np: n \in \mathbb N, p\in \mathcal P_{\mathbb Q}\}.$

Comment: Why do polynomials approximate also derivatives? Stone-Weierstrass says that, for any continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$, $p_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly, but not $p_n'\rightarrow f'$, right?

Comment: I think that the answer to my previous comment is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555712/on-finding-polynomials-that-approximate-a-function-and-its-derivative-extension).